# Identify and replace non-ASCII characters between brackets

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have tags (only ASCII chars inside brackets) of the following structure: `[Root.GetSomething]`, instead, some contributors ended up submitting contributions with Cyrillic chars that look similar to Latin ones, e.g. `[Rооt.GеtSоmеthіng]`.
I need to locate, and then replace those inconsistencies with the matching ASCII characters inside the brackets.

I tried `\[([АаІіВСсЕеРТтОоКкХхМ]+)\]`; `(\[)([^\x00-\x7F]+)(\])`, and some variations of the range but those searches don't see any matches. I seem to be missing something important in the regex execution logic.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70444612/edit) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: Try searching for the Cyrillic script with `\p{Cyrillic}+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex matching any "interesting" Cyrillic char in between `[` + letters or `.` +  `]` and a conditional replacement pattern:

*Find What*: `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[a-zA-Z.]*\K(?:(А)|(а)|(І)|(і)|(В)|(С)|(с)|(Е)|(е)|(Р)|(Т)|(т)|(О)|(о)|(К)|(к)|(Х)|(х)|(М))(?=[[:alpha:].]*])`
*Replace With*: `(?1A:?2a:?3I:?4i:?5B:?6C:?7c:?8E:?9e:?{10}P:?{11}T:?{12}t:?{13}O:?{14}o:?{15}K:?{16}k:?{17}X:?{18}x:?{19}M)`

Make sure *`Match Case`* option is ON. See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MXkyLC/2) with a [image] string:

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)` - end of the previous successful match or a `[` char
- `[a-zA-Z.]*` - zero or more `.` or ASCII letters
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the currently matched text from the overall match memory buffer
- `(?:(А)|(а)|(І)|(і)|(В)|(С)|(с)|(Е)|(е)|(Р)|(Т)|(т)|(О)|(о)|(К)|(к)|(Х)|(х)|(М))` - a non-capturing group containing 19 alternatives each of which is put into a separate capturing group
- `(?=[[:alpha:].]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more letters or `.` and then a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

The `(?1A:?2a:?3I:?4i:?5B:?6C:?7c:?8E:?9e:?{10}P:?{11}T:?{12}t:?{13}O:?{14}o:?{15}K:?{16}k:?{17}X:?{18}x:?{19}M)` replacement pattern replaces `А` with `A` (`\u0410`) if Group 1 matched, `а` (`\u0430`) with `a` if Group 2 matched, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I exactly needed.

Comment: However, I found that you misplaced the letter `M` in the replacement yourself. I know, it's so tricky;) It'll be great if N++ had an option to use different fonts for different alphabets..

Comment: @AlCrow Thanks for noticing. The replacement pattern is now fixed.